# Socket error connection 9100 on php zebra

Tags: python, php, zebra-printers

I try to send text on zebra ZD-420 with php code but receive error : Connection refused
I use codeigniter to connect i try 2 library but same error "Connetion refused", port is open but with php code .

i try use https://www.binarytides.com/php-socket-programming-tutorial/ but same don't work

```
        /* construct the label */
        $label = "^XA ^LH0,0 ^FO4,2 ^GB804,798,4 ^FS ^FO4,2 ^GB548,52,4 ^FS ^FO19,12 ^ADN,36,20 ^FDRossi
Andrea ^FS ^FO548,2 ^GB260,52,4 ^FS ^FO561,16 ^ADN,36,10 ^FDP/V ^FS ^FO611,16
^ADN,36,10 ^FD1:3 ^FS ^FO693,16 ^ADN,36,10 ^FD18/12/14 ^FS ^FO20,66 ^GB540,135,80 ^FS
^FO21,70 ^ADN,135,25 ^FR ^FDREGGIO CALABRIA ^FS ^FO720,66 ^GB72,135,80 ^FS ^FO721,70
^ADN,135,25 ^FR ^FD13 ^FS ^FO4,210 ^GB128,166,4 ^FS ^FO128,210 ^GB680,166,4 ^FS
^FO136,220 ^ADN,36,15 ^FDProva Rossi ^FS ^FO136,276 ^ADN,36,10 ^FDCONTRADA RAVAGNESE
GRAZIELLA,8 ^FS ^FO15,243 ^ADN,108,50 ^FDE5 ^FS ^FO136,338 ^ADN,36,14 ^FDReggio
Calabria ^FS ^FO580,338 ^ADN,36,15 ^FDRC ^FS ^FO632,210 ^GB176,166,4 ^FS ^FO660,220
^AAN,18,5 ^FDCALABRIA SICILIA ^FS ^FO695,246 ^ADN,18,5 ^FDCSN ^FS ^FO632, 273
^GB176,103,4 ^FS ^FO640,280 ^ADN,18,5 ^FDPeso Kg ^FS ^FO680,318 ^ADN,36,20 ^FD4.1 ^FS
^FO632, 372 ^GB176,48,4 ^FS ^FO640,378 ^ADN,18,5 ^FDPorto: ^FS ^FO658,398 ^ADN,18,10
^FDFRANCO ^FS ^FO4,372 ^GB804,48,4 ^FS ^FO25,383 ^ADN,36,10 ^FDNote: ^FS ^FO88,383
^ADN,36,10 ^FDProva Zaffignani ^FS ^FO640,650 ^XGE:GLSMINI.GRF,1,1 ^FS ^FO606,718
^GB202,82,4 ^FS ^FO4,718 ^GB606,82,4 ^FS ^FO240,718 ^GB144,80,40 ^FS ^FO242,724
^ADN,96,25 ^FR ^FD1-25 ^FS ^FO50,422 ^BY3 ^BCN,260,N,N,N,A ^FVWW540006975010RC ^FS
^FO50,685 ^ADN,27,15 ^FDWW 540006975 01 0 RC 01 ^FS ^XZ";

        $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
        if ($socket === false) {
            echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error    ()) . "\n";
        } else {
            echo "OK.\n";
        }

        echo "Attempting to connect to '$host' on port '$port'...";
        $result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port);
        if ($result === false) {
            echo "socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . socket_strerror    (socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
        } else {
            echo "OK.\n";
        }

        socket_write($socket, $label, strlen($label));
        socket_close($socket);
        socket_close($socket);
```

with python code works but on my host i can't use python.

```
 import socket
mysocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)         
host = "10.80.209.106" 
port = 9100   
try:           
    mysocket.connect((host, port)) #connecting to host
    mysocket.send(b"^XA^A0N,50,50^FO50,50^FDSocket Test^FS^XZ")#using bytes
    mysocket.close () #closing connection
except:
    print("Error with the connection")
```

Comment: you use `$result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port);` where is port variable?

Comment: Why you close socket 2 times?

Comment: i remove 1 socket_close and variable host and port is before $label.